# Is my understanding correct? "84 If you are a man who'd drop me for this; 85 won't you fall in love with me first?"

Tags: translation, meaning, manga

[image]

This is how I understand the sentence:

> 84 If you are a man who'd drop me for this
> 85 won't you fall in love with me first?

But it's such a weird thing to say. Something like "...you couldn't have liked me much to begin with." would make more sense to me, but it's not written. I think.

Context: It's a BL manga and one of the guys grew suddenly taller than the other and is now worried that his boyfriend doesn't want him anymore.

Comment: More context needed.  How do we know who is talking to who?  Is the 「男」 the listener or a third person?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> それで手放すような男なら
>   まず俺が好きになってねぇか

To show the hidden personal pronouns:

> （お前が、）それで（俺を）手放すような男なら
>   まず俺が（お前を）好きになってねぇか

It means...

> If you were a man who'd {dump me / give me up} {for this / because of that},
>   I wouldn't have fallen in love with you, to begin with.

俺が is the subject for (or, is the one who does the action) 好きになる.

Comment: Is an alternative interpretation not possible? (お前が)それで(俺を)手放すような男なら、まず俺(のこと)が好きになってねぇか *If you were a man who'd dump me for this, are you saying that you didn't fall in love with me?* (I'm somehow thrown off by か in your interpretation of the sentence.)

Comment: @Earthliŋ, Doesn't that `それで` mean `and` ( to connect sentences by jumping to another topic ) , so I guess there is nothing to refer with `for this`. And what does the last  `か` 's work here? Is it same as the confirmation `ね` in an angry way? I think the girl finished explaining sth. then she wanted to correct the guy about being dumped (which really annoyes her) that he cannot dump someone if it's a one sided love. So she souts at him:`I've never been in love with you, don't you get it `  Please correct me

Comment: @Earthliŋ 文法的にはそれも可能なのでしょうが、まずこの文を読んだら、「それで手放すような男なら」の部分は「好きになる」の目的語だな、って思うんです。「お前はそんな理由で手放すような男じゃない。そういうところがいいんだ。そういう部分を俺は好きになったんだ」って感じです。あと、もし「俺のことが」って意味なら、「それで手放すような男なら、俺なんかを/俺なんか好きになってねえか」とか「俺を好きになんかなってねぇか」と言う方が自然な気がします。最後の「か」は、「ああ、そうか。そうだよな。」という、思い直す感じの気持ちだと思います、英語にできませんが。すみません。

Comment: @mkb それで here means "because of that" / "for that reason".

Comment: That 「か」 at the end really bothered me because it's only used to pose a question, but I think I've figured it out. Because I don't know the context I can't be 100% sure, but this makes perfect sense if he's talking to himself or making a comment like "I guess ~~~". So in this situation it would be something along the lines of "But then again, I guess I wouldn't have fallen in love with you in the first place if you were the kind of man who would give up so easily over something like that".

Comment: @HalfwayDillitante そうそう、そんな感じです！英訳すごい上手～！…って当たり前**かぁ** …。うらやましい～～（´ρ｀）